# Задачка с сортировкой массива. С условием о их смежности в массиве

Tags: c++

Дан массив с 20 двузначных натуральных чисел. Переставить эти числа так, что бы любые два смежные числа отличались ровно одной цифрой. Прошу помочь с заданием.

Comment: А кто сказал, что это вообще возможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разобем задачу на две части. Первое - что такое два числа, которые отличаются на одну цифру. Тут надо подумать, так как может быть, 20 и 32 могут как подходить под условие, так и нет. Допустим, что эти числа подходят.

```
bool eq(int a, int b) {
  int a1 = a / 10;
  int a2 = a % 10;
  int b1 = b / 10;
  int b2 = b % 10;
  return (a1 == b1 && a2 != b2) || 
         (a1 == b2 && a2 != b1) || 
         (a2 == b1 && a1 != b2) || 
         (a2 == b2 && a1 != b1);
}
```

Теперь, имея такую функцию, строим граф их чисел. Узлы - это числа, а ребра - это если эти числа подходят под условие.

Теперь, когда граф есть, можно пробовать поискать в нем гамильтонов цикл. Если хотя бы один такой есть - он и будет ответом. Но только тут есть одно упрощение - гамильтонов цикл на то и цикл, что он всех выстраивает кольцо. Вам же по задаче этого не нужно. Поэтому, нужно просто искать такой путь, который проходит через все вершины (узлы). На таких размерах наиболее просто это сделать обычной рекурсией. Кстати, задачу можно сильно упростить, если граф "сжать" - можно убрать узлы, у которых только два ребра. Такой путь часто называют "полугамильтоновым".